# Maven Intellij IDEA failing to gwt compile classes

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea

I am getting this strange issue with Maven, Intellij IDEA with GWT compiling. I have this set up and working on my desktop pc but now that I have pulled the changes and loaded the project on my other computer I get this issue:

```
...snip... \EmailServiceImpl.java C:\Users\Szabolcs\Java\Workspace\ims-project\ims\src\main\java\nz\co\doltech\ims\shared\domains\InjuryType.java -s C:\Users\Szabolcs\Java\Workspace\ims-project\ims\target\generated-sources\annotations -g -nowarn -target 1.7 -source 1.7 -encoding UTF-8
[INFO] Compiling 370 source files to C:\Users\Szabolcs\Java\Workspace\ims-project\ims\target\ims-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \Users\Szabolcs\Java\Workspace\ims-project\ims\src\main\java\nz\co\doltech\ims\client\application\investigation\InvestigationPresenter.java:[126,26] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\Szabolcs\Java\Workspace\ims-project\ims\src\main\java\nz\co\doltech\ims\client\application\investigation\InvestigationPresenter.java:[126,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\Szabolcs\Java\Workspace\ims-project\ims\src\main\java\nz\co\doltech\ims\client\application\investigation\InvestigationPresenter.java:[123,84] error: type argument MyView is not within bounds of type-variable T
[ERROR] \Users\Szabolcs\Java\Workspace\ims-project\ims\src\main\java\nz\co\doltech\ims\client\application\investigation\InvestigationPresenter.java:[204,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\Szabolcs\Java\Workspace\ims-project\ims\src\main\java\nz\co\doltech\ims\client\application\investigation\InvestigationModule.java:[10,2] error: no suitable method found for bindPresenter(Class<InvestigationPresenter>,Class<MyView>,Class<InvestigationView>,Class<MyProxy>)
[INFO] 5 errors
```

Bigger log trace view: [here](http://pastebin.com/DTrQNizi)

File the error points to:

```
123 public class InvestigationPresenter extends IncidentPresenter<InvestigationPresenter.MyView, 
        InvestigationPresenter.MyProxy> implements InvestigationViewUiHandlers, ChangeSectionHandler {

126 interface MyView extends IncidentView, HasUiHandlers<InvestigationViewUiHandlers> {
        void setupValidation(Map<Integer, SectionTuple> sections);
        void flush();
        void limited(LimitType type);

... snip ...
```

InvestigationModule.java

```
public class InvestigationModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(InvestigationView.Resources.class).asEagerSingleton();

10      bindPresenter(InvestigationPresenter.class, InvestigationPresenter.MyView.class, 
            InvestigationView.class, InvestigationPresenter.MyProxy.class);
    }
}
```

This makes no sense. The IDE isn't showing an issue and it shouldn't be... Using the same compiler settings, same JDK same bytecode version etc. How could it work on my other machine but now not on this one that is essentially setup exactly the same?

- Javac 1.7
- JDK 7
- GWT 2.6.1
- Maven 3.1.0

I've tried:

- invalidating cache and restarting
- Deleting Intellij IDEA system directory then reimporting the maven project
- Double, triple, quadtruple checking the settings and config

Any help with this issue is appreciated.

Comment: What are #126, 123 and others code-line strings?

Comment: And what about `InvestigationModule` class?

Comment: Well, this all looks like part of your classes are in another module, which wasn't yet compiled and installed, or in your maven dependencies incorrect list of needed libraries is listed.

Comment: `your maven dependencies incorrect list of needed libraries is listed` how could this be when I have the exact same pom's as on my other computer which is compiling perfectly fine? I use git to manage the source so I know it is exactly the same.

Comment: I had such bugs in `IDEA`. Try to: 1) cut all dependencies from maven file (save it in another location) (editing file from IDEA!), 2) clean your maven repository, 3) again paste previously cutted depdendency list and allow to `IDEA` automatically reload all these libraries from remote repos.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the reason is still mysterious, the problem is linked to the fact that the JAVA compiler has a hard time figuring out the inheritance chain correctly while Eclipse and IntelliJ compilers are being a little bit more generous with what you can compile.

Extracting MyView from InvestigationPresenter will fix your problem.